# VBA - CallByName won't accept variant arguments

Tags: vba, excel, function

**Solution:** Just put brackets around Value in the CallByName statement to force evaluation of it.

Ex. `CallByName MobClass, TargetData, vbLet, (Value)`

Credit goes to Rory from the other post, which I will probably be deleting since it is no longer relevant and a possible duplicate.

I've spent a long time trying to figure out what was wrong with how I was using CallByName. I finally realized that its fourth argument (Args) will throw a type mismatch if the input is not either EXACTLY the same type as the input argument of what its calling or its hard-coded in.

(I don't even understand how, or why, it does this since `VarType(Variant/Integer) = VarType(Integer)`)

So I either need a way to make it accept variant inputs or convert variables from `Variant/Integer` to `Integer` (or create a new variable) without a giant select case.

Edit: So my question wasn't clear so I'll explain it in more detail. I have a bunch of classes that I want to cycle through and call the `Let` property on. My simplified setup is:

```
Dim AllClasses as Collection 
Sub SetAll(TargetProperty as String, Value as Variant)

    For each ClassX in AllClasses

        CallByName ClassX, TargetProperty, vbLet, Value

    Next ClassX

End Sub
```

The problem is `Value` when it is initialized as `Variant`. The only time I can get it to not throw a type mismatch exception is when I initialize `Value` as the exact same type that the property wants, but I can't do that since the data types in the class vary.

Edit 2: I'm going to ask another question about the whole problem since no one seems to know much about `CallByName`

Edit 3: Here's a summary of what we have so far:

- `CallByName`'s fourth argument (Args) throws a type mismatch when trying to call the `Let` property on a class.
- This only happens when the value trying to be assigned is stored in a `Variant` data type. It works perfectly if the variable is initialized to the same type the `Let` property is expecting OR if the value is hard-coded into the argument.
- The `Let` property works fine on its own. It accepts `Variant` data types just fine.
- My question is: **Is there a way to stop this exception?** I'm creating [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287139/vba-assign-a-value-to-multiple-classes-at-once-property-let) about other possible solutions to my overall problem.

Comment: You have sort of jumped to the punchline without the joke. Where is the code to go with this please?

Comment: If your called by name method expects an `Integer` you can type cast a variant to integer like `CallByName obj, "Test", VbMethod, CInt(v)`

Comment: `Cint(x)` doesn't work either, it still throws an exception.

Comment: Your edit helps, but it is still far from being a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, but I know what the problem is; that `CallByName` doesn't accept `Variant` data types for its last argument (Args). I'm asking if there is a workaround anyone can think of besides creating a large select case statement that catches the inputted data type and Dims a new variable in that type to pass to `CallByName`.

Comment: except the technical guidance says args() Optional: Variant ( Array ).

Comment: As I said in the post, its because the `Let` property I'm calling wants a specific data type, which causes `CallByName` to throw a type mismatch. I even said I don't know how this works since `VarType(Variant/Integer) = VarType(Integer)`.

Comment: To save you a comment, calling the `Let` property normally using a `Variant` data type works fine. It only fails when called by `CallByName`.

Comment: What about adding a properties collection to the class? By that you can let them without `CallByName`. You still don't show the class relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is that you pass the properties-arguments by reference not by value, but you can't pass a reference to a different datatype (variant -> long) as the types don't match and it can't be converted as this would change the data type in the caller too. By using brackets, you [force the argument to be passed by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-force-an-argument-to-be-passed-by-value) and it can be casted as type`Long`.

You can avoid this by using `ByVal`in the`Property Letter`instead of`ByRef`(what is implicit used if not set). You are aware that by referencing a variable, changes made in the property change the callers value too?

Example:

Class PassExample

```vb
'Save as class module PassExample
Public Property Let PropByVal(ByVal NewVal As Long)
NewVal = 1
End Property
Public Property Let PropByRef(ByRef NewVal As Long)
NewVal = 1
End Property
```

Module with test sub:

```vb
'save as standard module
Sub test()
Dim v As Variant
v = 0

Dim ExampleInstance As New PassExample

CallByName ExampleInstance, "PropByVal", VbLet, v 'this works
CallByName ExampleInstance, "PropByRef", VbLet, v 'type mismatch
CallByName ExampleInstance, "PropByRef", VbLet, (v) 'this works as ByRef is changed to byval
Debug.Print v ' shows 0, not 1 as it should be if referenced

CallByName ExampleInstance, "PropByRef", VbLet, CVar(v) ' works too as it passes a function-result that can't be referenced

End Sub
```

Thanks to Rory and chris neilsen for providing the solution!

Comment: That makes sense, sorry I didn't think of that before asking the question. I've been programming in C++ a lot and its default is pass by value so it never really crossed my mind.

Comment: @LeoSteeves no need for excuses, this was a good problem to think of for me. Learned a lot digging into this.. Just one wish ;) Improve your question with an example of your classes properties to clearfy the problem for others. For sure then you will get some more votes, as topic itself is not the usual I can't code do it for me ;) . A feedback for Display Names property class would be good too, as it is unclear if this was helpful for you.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287139/vba-assign-a-value-to-multiple-classes-at-once-property-let) for an alternative using classes