# How do I re-define the SQL in a QueryDef? I have code that works by deleting and re-creating the QueryDef, but I can't get the overwrite to work

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am told (and agree) that it is better to replace the SQL in an existing querydef, rather than delete and re-define the querydef each time the query needs to change.  But my code only seems to work the second way.  Here is the code I have that works:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim mySql As String
mySql = ""

mySql = "TRANSFORM COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS CountOfDocument " & _
            "SELECT tblDocs.[Contractor Dept], " & _
            "COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS [Total Of Document] " & _
            "FROM tblDocs " & _
            "GROUP BY tblDocs.[Contractor Dept] " & _
            "PIVOT tblDocs.[Engineering Status Code]"
On Error Resume Next
db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryX"                        'Remove temporary query if exists
Set QD = db.CreateQueryDef("qryX", mySql)         'create temporary query
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO tblDocsCrossTabX FROM qryX;"
```

Here is the code I can't get to work

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim mySql As String
mySql = " "
Set QD = db.CreateQueryDef(("qryX"), mySql)

mySql = "TRANSFORM COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS CountOfDocument " & _
            "SELECT tblDocs.[Contractor Dept], " & _
            "COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS [Total Of Document] " & _
            "FROM tblDocs " & _
            "GROUP BY tblDocs.[Contractor Dept] " & _
            "PIVOT tblDocs.[Engineering Status Code]"
QD.SQL = mySQL                                             'overwrite query SQL
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO tblDocsCrossTabX FROM qryX;"
```

Oddly, the second version doesn't throw any errors at me, but it doesn't make the crosstab table at all.

Edit:  Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  The problem is that the second set of code Does. Not. Execute. The. SQL.  If it executed the code, I would be happy to re-write and use the same temp query over and over, but it does. not. execute. the. SQL..

Please respond with how to make the code in the second block actually execute the indicated SQL statement and build the desired table.

I know I have to remake a query if I delete it.  Duh. 
I know I "should" be able to re-use the same query if I can get the Set statement to properly overwrite the previous sql with the desired sql.
I know you all want to provide an answer, but please make it an answer to the question I am asking.

Comment: If you run second version it will raise an error at least at second run (you can't create a query that allready exists) or you are hiding an error handler! You have to check if query allready exist before create it! My advice, use a temporary querydef and db.Execute.. Also remove the double parenthesis, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272430/type-mismatch-when-passing-string-variable-into-variant-parameter-and-assigning/51272853#51272853

Comment: MySQL tag is wrong unless you use Oracles MySQL Database as Backend!

Comment: Yes, the error handler is shown in the first code, where I delete and re-create the query every time I need to modify the query.  The second code does not show the 'clean up' code I use later on to remove all temporary objects, including the query, so it doesn't create an error.  This error I am familiar with.  But changing the .SQL part of a querydef isn't working for me, which is the crux of my problem.

Comment: On Error Resume Next without check the Err-Object later is no error handler, just a hider;( Second code has that too?  That explains why it diidn't show you the error on invalid sql statement(3129)!

Answer (score 1):

You can recycle the object if you don't delete it:

```vb
' On Error Resume Next
Set QD = db.QueryDefs("qryX")
QD.SQL = mySQL
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO tblDocsCrossTabX FROM qryX;"
```

Comment: That looks just like the code I tried that doesn't want to work.  Am I missing something?   Do I need to reexecute the line
  "Set QD = db.QueryDefs("qryX") 
every time I need to modify the query?

Comment: Even re-executing "Set QD = db.QueryDefs("qryX") every time doesn't seem to work.  It still doesn't create tblDocsCrossTabX.

Comment: You need setting it once only.

Comment: In the second set of code, the code I need help with, I only set it once.  It doesn't execute the SQL!

Comment: I think it should work, so I can't tell why it doesn't. Try running the query manually.

Comment: It does, sorry.  The difference was I was attempting to assign SQL to the querydef during creation (  CreateQueryDef(("qryX"), mySql)  )  but the string I tried to insert as SQL code isn't valid SQL.  So no querydef even got created.  Sorry for the frustration.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a subquery, you can use a tempory QueryDef instead of bothering with checking for`QueryDef`already existing or not, just combine the SELECT and the INSERT-Query to use a temporary`QueryDef`

Unfortunally you can't use`Transform`in a subquery so this code leads to`Runtime-Error 3129 Invalid SQL statement`.

```vb
Sql = "SELECT * INTO tblDocsCrossTabX FROM (TRANSFORM COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS CountOfDocument " & _
            "SELECT tblDocs.[Contractor Dept], " & _
            "COUNT(tblDocs.Document) AS [Total Of Document] " & _
            "FROM tblDocs " & _
            "GROUP BY tblDocs.[Contractor Dept] " & _
            "PIVOT tblDocs.[Engineering Status Code])"
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString) 'or db.CreateQueryDef("") creates a not named and therefore temporary QueryDef
    .SQL = Sql
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

Comment: I will try this out.  Thanks!

Comment: No luck.  Now I get the error " Invalid SQL statement; expected 'Delete', 'Insert', 'Procedure', 'Select', or 'Update'. "

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you can't use Transform in a subquery. Then you need a saved query and handle if to be created or not.

Comment: Admittedly, my original sql was pretty silly.  Selecting everything from a query and dumping it all into a temp table is awful when I could just use the query itself.  I have corrected that :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In the first block of code, when I delete and recreate the query, the string mySql contains a valid SQL statement, so Access is able to assign that SQL to the querydef when I completely recreate it with SET.  Specifically,

```
mySql = "Transform..."
```

Comes *Before*

```
Set QD = db.CreateQueryDef("qryX", mySql)
```

In the second set of code, the string mySql contains only a space when the Set command is used, as " " is not a valid SQL Statement, the Set command won't even get executed, and the QueryDef QD never even gets created.

Specifically, the error in the second code occurs because

```
mySql = " "  'NOT a valid SQL Statement
```

comes before the attempt to create the queryDef

```
Set QD = db.CreateQueryDef(("qryX"), mySql)   'QD never gets created because mySql is not valid SQL
```

preventing the assignment of a valid SQL statement later, and so no table gets created.

Comment: As you want to create an empty QueryDef in your second code and then edit it, you can do that by ommiting the sql-parameter on creation`.CreateQueryDef("qryX")`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of successful code.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim QueryString As String
Dim QDDocsCross As QueryDef
Set QDDocsCross = db.CreateQueryDef("DocsCross")

QueryString = "TRANSFORM COUNT(Docs.Document) AS CountOfDocument " & _
            "SELECT Docs.[Contractor Dept], " & _
            "COUNT(Docs.Document) AS [Total Of Document] " & _
            "FROM Docs " & _
            "GROUP BY Docs.[Contractor Dept] " & _
            "PIVOT Docs.[Engineering Status Code]"
        QDDocsCross.SQL = QueryString
```